# Combine JSON objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a method in events_controller.rb that I want to return a json object that combines data from Object.all and the rails_blob_path of the attached image to each JSON element. The images are not part of the events model but are attached.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def get_events
    @events = Event.all
    images = @events.map {|i| rails_blob_path(i.image)}
    render json: { data: @events, images: images}

  end

end
```

this renders

```
{"data":[{"id":7,"name":"New York Event","datetime":null,"location":"NYC","tickets":null,"created_at":"2020-06-04T15:21:23.656Z","updated_at":"2020-06-04T15:21:23.712Z","price":null}],"images":["/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ec449cf510b8b7dd19c83531422a4fbe47890f12/nyc.jpeg"]}
```

but I want "images" to be part of the "data" element so that I can query data.id, data.name and data.image.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
@events = Event.all.map { |e| e.attributes.merge(image: rails_blob_path(e.image)) }
render json: { data: @events }, status: 200
```